# Простое клиент-серверное приложение

Tags: java, сокет

Доброго времени суток!
Мне нужно написать программу, реализующую прямое глобальное соединение между двумя компьютерами. Я нашёл и проработал довольно много статей и кода в интернете, и для начала остановился на реализации, как тут http://www.quizful.net/post/java-socket-programming. Идеально работает на lockalhost и если задать как целевой IP - свой собственный, программно полученный как тут - http://cloud-notes.blogspot.ru/2012/05/java-ip.html, но только если он локальный, а соединение между двумя разными компьютерами, или своим собственным, но через глобальный IP уже не проходит. Пали подозрения на NAT - но между двумя изолированными друг от друга компьютерами с прямым доступом в интернет, (определено материалами этой [https://ru.wikibooks.org/wiki/Сетевой_порт/Что_такое_NAT_и_как_определить,_находитесь_ли_вы_за_NAT](https://ru.wikibooks.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE_%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5_NAT_%D0%B8_%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA_%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C,_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8C_%D0%BB%D0%B8_%D0%B2%D1%8B_%D0%B7%D0%B0_NAT) статьи) тоже ничего не получилось. Прокси не используется, (смотрел тут http://www.lagado.com/proxy-test) брандмауэр отключён на обоих машинах. Тестировал много раз, и в глобальной сети, и в локальной(роутер), но безуспешно. Где-то читал, что большинство провайдеров выдаёт динамические IP, поэтому и не проходит подключение по заранее оговоренному, но это не решает проблему, по которой не соединяются компьютеры в локальной сети. Пересмотрел все предыдущие вопросы на (как ни странно) StackOverflow, но конкретного решения не нашёл, не смотря на несколько идентичных проблем.

Буду очень благодарен, если: (любое из нижеследующего)

- Подскажут возможные причины и их обход(годятся *абсолютно все* предположения)

- Дадут код/ссылку на код с готовой реализацией, учитывающей эту проблему

- Подскажут альтернативный механизм простого прямого соединения между двумя удалёнными/локальными компьютерами силами Java

*Используется:* Java 1.8.0_101 *под платформой Windows 7, и модем Yota, либо* *напрямую, либо через роутер фирмы Asus. Брандмауэр и антивирус на время тестирования отключены.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Причина в том, чтобы найти компьютер в сети используется IP адрес. Однако в случае NAT у вас вообще нет своего адреса, а в случае динамического - нет постоянного. Тут есть три варианта:

1. Купить айпи адрес. Хотя бы один. Тогда один компьютер будет сервером, другой клиентом.
2. Читать про P2P сети. Тут конечно для соединения все равно потребуется выделенный сервер. Однако можно будет найти бесплатный хостинг и там уже на php написать всё.
3. Читать про DynDNS. В случае динамического айпи можно будет поднять сервер. Но я с этим не работал, так что гугл вам в помощь ) Либо более конкретный вопрос на SO в зависимости от того, что вы выберете.

**UPD** Не заметил про локальные сети. В первую очередь убедитесь, что IP адреса указаны правильно. Вбейте ipconfig в консоли и убедитесь, что в клиенте действительно указан адрес сервера, а в сервере - адрес клиента. Хотя честно говоря я так и не понял из вашего текста, заработало или нет у вас соединение по локальной сети через локальные адреса.